# Trying to remove a fragment from the screen Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I'm within an activity and I launch a fragment from there, and it appears on the screen fine, but I want to use the button to then remove the same fragment. I can't see what's wrong with the code, I know it's going in to the code that should remove it because the toast says "remove fragment". Any ideas? Thanks

```
    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (showFrag == true){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                showFrag = false;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Show Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (showFrag == false){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Remove Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showFrag = true;
        }
}


}
```

Comment: to pop a fragment of `backstack` you need to add it to backstack first. You can do that by calling `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)` after you call `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);`

Comment: you don't have to start a FragmentTransaction to call popBackStack()

Comment: Let me post that as a answer so that other people having the same problem can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pop a fragment of `backstack` you need to add it to `backstack` first.
You can do that by calling `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)` after you call `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);`

Also including @coelho 's comment - You dont have to start a FragmentTransaction to call popBackStack().

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling addToBackStack before :)

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

The the remove should simply be:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

No need to create a local variable and no need to create a transaction.

Comment: Meh, just realized Varun had added this to the comments as well.